Name of cult horror movie from the 80s about a heavy metal fanatic
I ve seen some years ago just the beginning of a horror movie, 
as i remember from the description of the back of the movie and the remnants in my memore, there are the following characteristics about the movie:

one or more heroes are fanatics of heavy metal and wear the typical clothes associated with 80s metal subculture like jeans and patches.
there is a scene involving a swimming pool
the hero is rather reluctant to go to school
the movie was named a "cult movie"


You may be thinking of the 1986 movie "Trick or Treat", which has appearances by Gene Simmons of Kiss and Ozzy Osbourne.
Per user comments on IMDB, this is a heavy metal horror movie and is considered a cult classic:

"The plot outline is your standard Heavy Metal horror movie. Kid's favorite singer dies. Kid plays record backwards. Hero comes back in demonic form and rocks the town."
"If you grew up in the 80's and love Heavy Metal, this is the Movie for you."
"All in all, I give this cult classic a perfect 10."
"This film is the most cult movie on metal there is."

IMDB also says there is a pool scene in the movie:

A boy is almost drowned after he is thrown into a pool with a weight stuck in his backpack.


You really should mention the film stars Kiss legend Gene Simmons.
